# Batchfile script in background READ Text first

Tags: batch-file

I'm remaking a MMORPG in batch.
Its almost complete, i'm currently writing a Instance Dunegon script.
I'm trying to broadcast a message with:

```
:Countdown
set Broadcast=King Albireo is spawning in 5 seconds...
set Countdown=5
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
set Broadcast=King Albireo is spawning in 4 seconds...
set Countdown=4
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
set Broadcast=King Albireo is spawning in 3 seconds...
set Countdown=3
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
set Broadcast=King Albireo is spawning in 2 seconds...
set Countdown=2
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
set Broadcast=King Albireo is spawning in 1 seconds...
set Countdown=0
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
if "%Countdown%" == "0" goto Main
goto Countdown
```

But when i run this in my script it pauses the game for 5 seconds.
Can someone fix this so the script dont pauses. Like the broadcast in the background.

Comment: Just delete the ping commands...

Comment: the complete sequence seems to be complete useless

Answer (score 0):

I think, what your Code is *meant* to do is :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM create a CarriageReturn:
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

for /L %%i in (5,-1,0) do (
  <nul set /p =King Albireo is spawning in %%i seconds...!CR!
  ping -n 2 127.0.01 >nul
)
goto Main
```

But if you don't want that 5 seconds delay, just remove the whole sequence.